# The time consume is not normal in multi-thread in Windows

Tags: multithreading

The time consume is not normal in multi-thread in Windows. Our device has 5 nozzles, the process is:

1. The nozzles pick chips up at the same time, so I use the 5 threads do it
2. Move the nozzles to another place
3. Put the chips

It's smooth at normal time, but sometimes it has a short stop before moving to another place (we can see it obviously). Picking chips takes about 80 milliseconds at normal time, and sometimes it becomes 130 milliseconds. I write a simple code to test it:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <WINDOWS.H>
#include <PROCESS.H>
#include <iostream>
#include <Mmsystem.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

using namespace std;

static TIMECAPS                 l_timecaps;

UINT WINAPI MainThread(LPVOID lParam /* = NULL */);
UINT WINAPI TestThread(LPVOID lParam /* = NULL */);
void MainProcess();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //set current process priority as real time
    SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);

    //use more accurate time
    timeGetDevCaps(&l_timecaps, sizeof(l_timecaps));
    timeBeginPeriod(l_timecaps.wPeriodMin);

    UINT uiThreadId = 0;
    HANDLE hEvents = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, MainThread, NULL, 0, &uiThreadId);
    SetThreadPriority(hEvents, THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);

    WaitForSingleObject(hEvents, INFINITE);

    cerr << endl << "Press Enter to exit." << endl;
    while (cin.get() != '\n');

    timeEndPeriod(l_timecaps.wPeriodMin);

    return 0;
}

UINT WINAPI MainThread(LPVOID lParam /* = NULL */)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100)
    {
        MainProcess();
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}

void MainProcess()
{
    const int THREAD_NUMBER = 5;
    static HANDLE hEvents[THREAD_NUMBER]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_NUMBER; ++i)
        hEvents[i] = NULL;

    //log time with more accurate time
    LARGE_INTEGER liPerfFreq={0};
    LARGE_INTEGER liBeginRunTime = {0}; 
    long lBeginRunTime = 0; 
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&liPerfFreq); 
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&liBeginRunTime);
    lBeginRunTime = liBeginRunTime.QuadPart * 1000 / liPerfFreq.QuadPart;

    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_NUMBER; ++i)
    {
        UINT uiThreadId = 0;
        hEvents[i] = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, TestThread, NULL, 0, &uiThreadId);
        SetThreadPriority(hEvents[i], THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);

        //assign to cpu
        SetThreadAffinityMask(hEvents[i], 0x00000001 + i);
    }

    //wait all threads finished
    WaitForMultipleObjects(THREAD_NUMBER, hEvents, TRUE, INFINITE);

    LARGE_INTEGER liEndRunTime = {0};
    long lEndRunTime = 0; 
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&liEndRunTime);
    lEndRunTime = liEndRunTime.QuadPart * 1000 / liPerfFreq.QuadPart;

    cout << "time: " << lEndRunTime - lBeginRunTime << endl;
}


UINT WINAPI TestThread(LPVOID lParam /* = NULL */)
{
    //do nothing
    return 0;
}
```

The output result time is 2,3 or 4 millisecond, but sometimes it becomes 57 or 62 millisecond. It's bad for our device when running, the device becomes slow.

Comment: what platform are you doing this test? (cores ? hyperthreading ?)

Comment: how many cores? Multithreading?

Comment: @Arno there are 2 cores and 4 multithreadings

Comment: You should look at your `SetThreadAffinityMask` with the mask being up to `0x00000001 + THREAD_NUMBER = 5 - 1` and your system does not support that `cpu`. Always look at the fuctions return value. You should get **ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER** in this case. This way it is likely, that two of the 5 threads are forced to operate on the same _logical cpu_.

Comment: I try to update THREAD_NUMBER as 4, and I still get the result: time consuming is 52

Comment: Even update THREAD_NUMBER as 2, and recycle run to 500 times, it still get the same result: time consuming is 51.     Only set THREAD_NUMBER to 1, it's fine.

Comment: make your `TestThread` doing something for a noticable time to evaluate the performance.

Comment: **And:** You may ask yourself whether you are dealing with the [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Arno I try it before, do something in 'TestThread', like Sleep(10), it gets the same result, so do nothing now in 'TestThread'

Comment: A Sleep is just wrong at this point.

Comment: @Arno Our device has 5 nozzles, the process is:  
1. The nozzles pick chips up at the same time, so I use the 5 threads do it.  2. Move the nozzles to another place    
3. Put the chips    
It's smooth at normal time, but sometimes it has a short stop before moving another place(we can see it obviously)    
Picking chips takes about 80 ms at normal time, and sometimes it becomes 130 ms

Comment: oups, you worried about 50 microseconds in your question Now it turns to 50 ms?

Comment: @Arno OMG, it should be millisecond, not microseconds. It's my mistake

Comment: @Arno I found one interesting thing, it gets more 50 ms in debug mode in VS2012, and it gets only 0 or 1 ms if running the exe directly. Does the VS2012 affect it?

Answer (score 0):

Your test threads do nothing. All the time is spent creating and shutting down the thread. Overheads in the kernel object manager and scheduler will dominate. Perhaps some of the threads are having to wait on other threads holding (via API calls) kernel locks and thus seeing delays.

And of course those inner threads could be completing before the call to set their priority completes: to set this you really need to start the thread suspended and then start it.

Because you are measuring nothing, all you have are overheads which will depend on what else is going on.

Also remember, while you have names like `THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL` Windows is not a real-time OS.

Comment: Yes, you are right to set their priority as you said.

Comment: And we still do not know what's going on in windows, and how to avoid it

Comment: @JackyZhou See the last paragraph. Variations of a few tens of milliseconds are normal (scheduler quantum). If you need concistency at that level of timing you need a proper RTOS.

Comment: It's hard for me to migrate the project from windows to RTOS, I am not familiar with RTOS, and the project is a little complicated

Comment: @JackyZhou "RTOS" = "Real Time Operating System" not something specific. If you are deep into a project with real time requirements without ensuring your platform cannot meet those requirements you have a problem for which there is no easy solution.

Comment: Hi Richard, I found the reason, it gets more 50 ms in debug mode in VS2012, and it gets only 0 or 1 ms if running the exe directly. Does the VS2012 affect it?

Comment: @JackyZhou Debugging (build, attaching a debugger) will have significant impact. Only take timing information in an optimised build without a debugger attached.